# Cannot access Firebase object attributes. Value displayed as undefined ANGULARFIRE

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I want to do a custom login for a demo of my doing, but I encountered a problem.

I use the username to access a reference url inside Firebase, I get a returned object. If I want to access a single attribute, I get the undefined value, but if I add in my html `{{returnedObj.name}}` the value is displayed.

Why is that?

```
angular.module('Demo').controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', '$location',    function($scope, $firebase, $location){
$scope.user = {};
$scope.check = function(){
    console.log('https://fabritzio-demo.firebaseio.com/users/' + $scope.user.name);
    $scope.returnedObj = $firebase(new Firebase('https://fabritzio-demo.firebaseio.com/usuarios/' + $scope.user.name)).$asObject();
    alert($scope.returnedObj.name); // returns undefined value
};
```

}]);

Comment: Firebase values are loaded asynchronously. Is it possible that the value hasn't loaded yet when the alert fires?

Comment: Try `$scope.returnedObj.$loaded().then(....)` ?

Comment: I just tried $scope.returnedObj.$loaded().then(function(){alert($scope.returnedObj.name)}). It displays the value. Is there an explanation? I would like to understand the cause

Comment: The cause is what @afternoon said already: Firebase loads the values asynchronously. So by calling `$loaded` you ask it for a so-called promise object for when the data is actually loaded. By calling `then` you can then execute code after the data has loaded.

Comment: There are many similar examples of asynchronous operations, though most of them will take a callback function instead of working with promises. E.g. the regular (non-Angular) Firebase API uses a `ref.on('value', function(snapshot) { /* your code here */ })` construct. The function is called when the value is first available or whenever it changes. This is another example of an asynchronous call.

Comment: I really appreciate your comments, now I have a better idea of this Api and the libraries.

Answer (score 12):

Firebase values are loaded asynchronously. The value will not yet have been loaded into `$scope.returnedObj` when the `alert` fires.

There are a couple of ways to handle values loading asynchronously from Firebase, for example using `$loaded` to get a promise:

```
$scope.returnedObj.$loaded().then(function () {
  alert($scope.returnedObj.name);
});
```

The value is displayed in the template because Angular watches all `$scope` variables for changes. When the value is loaded (milliseconds later), it is immediately displayed.