# Object property is undefined in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

The following works for me:

HTML:

```
{{user.uid}}
```

JS:

```
"use strict";

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, Auth) {

$scope.user = Auth.user;
});
```

but

HTML:

```
{{uid}}
```

JS:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, Auth) {
 $scope.uid = Auth.user.uid;
});
```

doesn't work, and it's because Auth.user.uid is undefined! Why is this happening? Why can we call attributes within the view but not within the controller? What should I do if i want to call an attribute within the controller?

Comment: does `Auth.user` return a promise?

Comment: @Claies my guess is something somewhere else is populating `Auth.user` asynchronously. It wouldn't be a promise itself

Comment: @Phil yes, like a promise from `$http`.  either way, without seeing the code for `Auth`, we can only guess at the real issue.

Comment: My bad guys - I'm pretty sure I have the same problem as in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450325/cannot-access-firebase-object-attributes-value-displayed-as-undefined-angularfi - should I delete this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely to occur because at the time you assign `Auth.user.uid` to the scope, that attribute does not exist. It is assigned at a later time to the `user` object, but because you have mapped the value directly to `$scope`, it won't update the way you would like it to. Here is an example of how this could happen:

```
.service('Auth', function($http){
    this.user = {};
    // this server call takes some amount of time to complete,
    // and until it does user.uid is undefined
    var self = this;
    $http.get('http://someurl', function(result){
        self.user.uid = result.uid;
    });
});

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, Auth){
    // this is called before the $http call is completed inside Auth
    $scope.uid = Auth.user.uid;

    // this is also called before the $http call completed, but because user exists, its children cause a scope change and notification
    $scope.user = Auth.user;
});
```

Now the way you have it working, by binding the `user` object to the scope is a much better way of doing it anyway. It is good practice to only bind container objects to `$scope`.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's the `$http` promise resolution that trigger the digest cycle, thus updating the template. JavaScript's object referencing means `Auth.user` is the same object as `$scope.user`

Comment: Just wondering - why is it good practice to only bind container objects to $scope?

Comment: Primarily because you guarantee the $scope level that you are trying to access (essential for things like ng-model too). Just research how angular scope hierarchies work, and why a dot is important.