# Dot notation showing up as undefined in AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

```
{
"$id":"-KMVCUSAsz92c0Hp296i",
"$priority":null,
"aQuestion":"what is your favorite color",
"option1":{"option":"red","vote":1},
"option2":{"option":"blue","vote":2},
"option3":{"option":"green","vote":0},
"option4":{"option":"yellow","vote":0}
}
```

So using dot notation to access this object from Firebase, using `vm.data.$id` and `vm.data.$priority` returns the correct value. However using `vm.data.aQuestion` or `vm.data.option1` yields `undefined`. I've looked at several posts, however none have fixed this issue for me. Is there something simple I'm not understanding?

Comment: Do you know what this `vm` means?

Comment: var vm = this; Same as  this.data.option1;

Comment: Use the key name after the dot operator, in ur case should be`vm.data.$id,vm.data.option1`

Comment: I've tried that, however it comes up as undefined for any key name other than $id and $priority. $id and $priority are default values given by firebase, not sure if that's why those are the only key names that are working when I use them after the dot operator

Comment: Try this vm.data["aQuestions"]

Comment: Hi, I tried bracket notation just now also, and it didn't work as well.

Comment: Actually this is not possible try to see have you did something which are making this field null or empty.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I may have figured it out. I was luckily able to find this post shortly after reading Surjeet's about something making my field null or empty.

[Cannot access Firebase object attributes. Value displayed as undefined ANGULARFIRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450325/cannot-access-firebase-object-attributes-value-displayed-as-undefined-angularfi)

Because Firebase values are loaded asynchronously, the value did not load. after using vm.data.$loaded().then was I able to retrieve through dot notation. Not sure if this is the best way, but it works. Thanks everyone for your help.

Also, if anyone that reads this has a better way to go about this issue, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You're right, but also see this advice from a Firebase developer https://medium.com/google-developers/the-single-biggest-angular-and-firebase-code-smell-and-how-to-fix-it-a0d1ef96ca65

Answer (score 0):

Try to see have you did something in your code which is making your object field null.

If not then,

Try this one `vm.data['aQuestion']`